# Database Model for Product Customization Options

Tags: database, database-design, model, database-schema

I'm in the process of designing an e-commerce where various items will have different customization options per product and am thinking of the best way to structure my database. For example, I may want to sell something in red or white as well as in different sizes but another piece may only be sold in green or red and not have a size option. I have a bunch of naive approaches I've outlined below but wonder if anyone has any ideas. I'd like to keep this relational unless there's a strong reason to move to NoSQL.

1. **Option 1:** Come up with a separate table for each type of option. For example, a table that has a list of all possible colors, another table that references this table with a subset of colors and is also associated with a product. There will then be another table to deal with the colors selected for the actual product that was added to the cart.
2. **Option 2:** Since the number of options per product will be minimal, why not just have a set of columns that contain values for each possible option. This would basically be the product table having a text column called "colors" that would then just list the color options available. I personally don't like this one since it's too limiting - what if I want to associate an image with each color or change pricing depending on the option?
3. **Option 3:** A combination of the previous two where each product will have a set of columns that will reference the available customization options. For example, each product will have a "color options" column that, if not null, will be available for that product and point to a well structured set of options.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 4:**

Have an option table that handles more than one option.

```
Option
------
Option ID
Item ID
Category ID
Category Text
```

Option ID is an auto incrementing sequential number.

Item ID is an integer that points back to the item.

Category ID is an integer representing a category.  For instance, Color would be 1, Size would be 2.

Category Text is the actual color or size.

This method makes sense **if and only if** you don't want to search for all the red items sold or all the XL items sold.

This type of data design is called an [entity / attribute data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I'd also need to put in a mapping for each product that gives the valid options for that category. I don't see why it would prevent me from searching for red items sold or XL items sold. As long as I know what the options are for each product and the configuration of the product sold I should be able to write a query to get at that information.

Comment: @Dan Goldin: Yes, you can write that query to get all the red items sold or all the XL items sold.  Just don't come back here and complain when that query runs dog slow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following schema:

**Table 'Products'**

```
Product id
Product name
Product base price
```

**Table 'Sizes'**

```
Size ID
Size name
Additional price
```

**Table 'Colours'**

```
Colour ID
Colour Name
Additional price
```

**Table 'SaleItems'**

```
SaleItem ID
Product ID
Size ID
Colour ID
```

Customers would buy items contained in the 'SaleItems' table. An example of a item would be a polo t-shirt which comes in four different sizes and three different colours. This way, you would have twelve rows in the 'SaleItems' table, each with differing characteristics, but be able to know how many polo shirts were sold, how many red shirts (of all types of product were sold), how many XL items, etc.

You may not need the price fields, but the idea is that the basic polo t-shirt costs 10 units; small size has no added price whereas XL has 10% extra price. Most colours would probably cost the same, but some exotic colour might cost 10% more. An XL polo t-shirt in this exotic colour would then cost 10 * 1.1 * 1.1 = 12.1 units.

This schema assumes that all products can have all sizes and colours.